# What is the equivalent under Clion of "Go to all" in Visual Studio(triggered by Ctrl+T)?

Tags: visual-studio, clion

So I use this functionality under Visual Studio to find all the classes with matching names, also sometimes to find the opened files in the past(which are closed).
Are there any equivalent under Clion?

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer myself, basically "Search everywhere" is the closest functionality Clion offered which can be compared with Go to all in Visual Studio.
This "Search everywhere" can be triggered by double tab the shift key.